# Getting multiple checkbox values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a series of checkboxes in a side panel, defined as follows inside a `sidebarPanel`:

```
sliderInput("days", 
                "Days to monitor:", 
                min = 1, 
                max = 50, 
                value = 5),
    checkboxInput("display_CMC", "Carolinas Medical Center", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("display_MariaParham", "Maria Parham", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("display_WakeMed", "Wake Med", TRUE)
```

I'd like to transform those results into a character vector in a programmatic way (e.g. if I had a checkboxInput with a name '`display_` I want it to automatically parse the results).  To do that, I tried:

```
displayIdx <- grep( "display_", names(input) )
facilityCode_keep <- names(input)[ displayIdx ][ input[ displayIdx ] ]
```

Unfortunately, that results in:

```
Error: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed.
```

Two questions:

1. How do I transform a series of `checkboxInput`s into a character vector?
2. What's up with the disallowing single bracket indexing.  I could understand if I was trying to assign to `input`, but I'm not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How do I transform a series of checkboxInputs into a character vector?**

You can use double-bracket indexing. But in this case you might consider using `checkboxGroupInput` function instead, which returns a character vector of the selected values.

**Why not single-bracket indexing?**

Single-bracket indexing is subsetting, while double-bracket indexing is element retrieval (or something like that). The input object is more like a map/hash/dict/environment than like a named vector, so subsetting doesn't really make sense. (Similarly, you can't single-bracket index on R's environment objects, you can only double-bracket index.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Any idea why single-bracket indexing is not allowed?

Comment: Single-bracket indexing is subsetting, while double-bracket indexing is element retrieval (or something like that). The `input` object is more like a map/hash/dict/environment than like a named vector, so subsetting doesn't really make sense. (Similarly, you can't single-bracket index on R's environment objects, you can only double-bracket index.)

Comment: Thanks for the really informative answer.  I've added it to your response.

Comment: There are contexts where it would be useful to be able to subset the input object, for example if you wanted to make an event listener for a dynamic set of inputs using something like this: reactive([input[grepl(pattern = "prefix",names(input))]},{...}) as an input to an eventReactive(). Which can be done with explicit lists of inputs see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/