# How to listen for more than one event expression within a Shiny eventReactive handler

Tags: r, shiny

I want two different events to trigger an update of the data being used by various plots / outputs in my app. One is a button being clicked (`input$spec_button`) and the other is a point on a dot being clicked (`mainplot.click$click`).

Basically, I want to listed for both at the same time, but I'm not sure how to write the code. Here's what I have now:

in server.R:

```
data <- eventReactive({mainplot.click$click | input$spec_button}, {
    if(input$spec_button){
      # get data relevant to the button
    } else {
      # get data relevant to the point clicked
    }
  })
```

But the if-else clause doesn't work

`Error in mainplot.click$click | input$spec_button : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

--> Is there some sort of action-combiner function I can use for the `mainplot.click$click | input$spec_button` clause?

Comment: Can you check output of !is.null(input$spec_button)?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I know this is old, but I had the same question. I finally figured it out. You include an expression in braces and simply list the events / reactive objects. My (unsubstantiated) guess is that shiny simply performs the same reactive pointer analysis to this expression block as to a standard `reactive` block.

```
observeEvent({ 
  input$spec_button
  mainplot.click$click
  1
}, { ... } )
```

*EDIT*

Updated to handle the case where the last line in the expression returns NULL. Simply return a constant value.

Comment: Changing accepted answer to this one since it seems to be a better solution than my original solution.

Comment: Can you identify which event was triggered?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've done this in a few cases by keeping track of them in separate variables and doing the comparison myself to see which has changed. But it's ugly. Probably better to put the main code in a function, then have two observeEvents that call the fn and then do specific stuff for each event.

Comment: Just a warning: `observeEvent` uses `ignoreNULL = TRUE` by default, which means if `mainplot.click$click` (the return value) is `NULL`, the handler will **never** be called even if `input$spec_button` changed. I'd recommend something like @JustAnother's answer to prevent falling into this trap.

Comment: Another warning: in my testing I found that this bracket syntax (`{}`) REQUIRES each event to be on its own newline, otherwise it fails with "Error in parse..." as soon as the parser encounters the second event. e.g., all on one line: `observeEvent({input$spec_button mainplot.click$click}, {...})` fails.  @JustAnother's answer using S3 Generic combine syntax (`c()`) works regardless of newlines.

Comment: Good call @gregL - that probably explains the issue @john-paul reports. I agree, probably better to use `c(...)` in most cases, unless there is a reason for `ignoreNULL` functionality.

Comment: We need to concat both expressions with "c()" instead of the method above. The answer below by@JustAnother is the right one !

Comment: I did some more thinking about this. If all the expressions return NULL then I think both answers will return NULL and the handler will not be triggered (since `c(NULL, NULL)` returns `NULL`) I'm editing my answer to account for this. @JustAnother's answer could do the same using `c(..., 1)`.

Answer (score 67):

Also:

```
observeEvent(c( 
  input$spec_button,
  mainplot.click$click
), { ... } )
```

Comment: While this looks very similar to @DuncanBrown 's answer, I found a situation where 2 action buttons both trigger a modal, this worked, and the `{` version  did not. I can't account for why that is so.

Comment: Added a comment to @Duncan Brown's answer on how this answer is different (and better IMO)

Comment: This one doesn't work for me - I get an error (shiny 1.0.5)

Comment: is there a way to find out which event was triggered? lets say I have two buttons, `input$button1` and `input$button2` that do very similar things, just with a different index. I would like to avoid to copy the code multiple times just because I don't know the index. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I've solved this issue with creating a reactive object and use it in event change expression. As below:

```
xxchange <- reactive({
paste(input$filter , input$term)
})

output$mypotput <- eventReactive( xxchange(), {
...
...
...
} )
```

Comment: This is a very good answer which could benefit from more explanation.  While the accepted answer is more straightforward making it better for rudimentary programs, this answer is better suited to large and complex codes. Two points seem missing from the answer (1)  Paste (or list) puts the two events on the same line making the code more compact.  (2) The reactive object saves the effort of repeating the same two events over and over if more than one listener is listening for the same set of events.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution I came up with: basically, create an empty `reactiveValues` data holder, and then modify its values based on two separate `observeEvent` instances.

```
  data <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$spec_button, {
    data$data <- get.focus.spec(input=input, premise=premise, 
                                itemname=input$dropdown.itemname, spec.info=spec.info)
  })
  observeEvent(mainplot.click$click, {
    data$data <- get.focus.spec(input=input, premise=premise, mainplot=mainplot(),
                                mainplot.click_focus=mainplot.click_focus(),
                                spec.info=spec.info)  
  })
```

Comment: will `list(mainplot.click$click, input$spec_button)` also work for OP's way.

Answer (score 6):

This can still be done with eventReactive by putting your actions in a vector.

```
eventReactive(
  c(input$spec_button, mainplot.click$click), 
{ ... } )
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea here is to create a reactive function which will execute the condition you want to pass in observeEvent and then you can pass this reactive function to check the validity of the statement. For instance:

```
validate_event <- reactive({
    # I have used OR condition here, you can use AND also
    req(input$spec_button) || req(mainplot.click$click)
})

observeEvent(validate_event(), 
    { ... } 
)
```

Keep Coding!