# How to listen for more than one event expression within a Shiny observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want two different events to trigger an observer. It was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha) that this should work. But it seems that it depends only on the second event.

```
observeEvent({ 
  input$spec_button
  mainplot.click$click
}, { ... } )
```

Have a look at the example.

```
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    actionButton("test1", "test1"),
    actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observeEvent({
        input$test1
        input$test2
    }, {
        print('Hello World')
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Once you click button test1 nothing happens. If you click button test2 it prints to your console. Once test2 button was pressed clicking test1 prints the message. That is a strange behaviour.

Another suggestion in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha) link was to use

```
list(input$test1, input$test2)
```

Which prints the message even without clicking the buttons.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should do it, note that you still have to check if the buttons were clicked as mentioned by @MrFlick

#### 1. You can use reactive expression

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  actionButton("test1", "test1"),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  toListen <- reactive({
    list(input$test1,input$test2)
  })
  observeEvent(toListen(), {
    if(input$test1==0 && input$test2==0){
      return()
    }
    print('Hello World')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### 2. As per example given by @MrFlick (now deleted)

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  actionButton("test1", "test1"),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$test1 | input$test2, {
    if(input$test1==0 && input$test2==0){
      return()
    }
    print('Hello World')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It prints 'Hello World' at first even if any buttons aren't pressed.

Comment: no it doesn't, copy and paste this code into it again

Comment: I see now :) Thanks

Comment: `return() ` in the above answer seems a clunky way. Instead can't we just say: `if(input$test1!=0 | input$test2!=0) print('Hello World')` ?

Comment: Using `req(input$test1!=0 | input$test2!=0)` instead of the `if` feels more idiomatic.

Comment: `req` was introduced relatively recently, I don't think it existed back in Jan2017, when this was answered

Comment: @jzadra, all works fine `R version 4.1.0` and `shiny_1.6.0`

Comment: #2 won't work if the inputs are not `actionButton()`s but, for example, `selectInput()`s.

Answer (score 20):

Using the `|` operator in the `observeEvent()` `eventExpr` won't work if the inputs are not numeric, logical or complex types.

For example, notice the message at the end of running this simple Shiny app with an `actionButton()` *and* a `selectInput()` used inside the `observeEvent()` `eventExpr`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  selectInput("test1", "test1", choices = c("a", "b")),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$test1 | input$test2,
  {
    print('Hello World')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6563
#> Warning: Error in |: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or
#> complex types
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Instead, you can create a list of the inputs inside the `observeEvent()` and include `ignoreInit = TRUE` if you wish to not print "Hello World" on app initialization. This approach accommodates any input types.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  selectInput("test1", "test1", choices = c("a", "b")),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, list(
    input$test1,
    input$test2
  ),
  {
    print('Hello World')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

If the `observeEvent(list(input$a, input$b), {...})` approach doesn't float your boat, then I can recommend the `reactive({list(input$a, input$b})` approach which goes like this:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  selectInput("test1", "test1", choices = c("a", "b")),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  event_trigger <- reactive({
    list(input$test1, input$test2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE, event_trigger(),
  {
    print('Hello World')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This approach has the advantage of being portable, meaning you can use it as the `eventExpr` for multiple `observeEvent()` calls (or other listeners) if needed.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I've updated the answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way to determine which of the events triggered?

Answer (score 3):

*observeEvent* is a wrapper for complex *observe* cases. In this particular case of an action when one or other reactive value changes, one could use a simple *observe.* This works:

```
require(shiny)    
ui <- basicPage(
      actionButton("test1", "test1"),
      actionButton("test2", "test2")
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session){
    
      observe( {
        input$test1
        input$test2
        if(input$test1==0 && input$test2==0){
          return()
        }
        print('Hello World')
        })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is a point in using *observeEvent* with options to eliminate the return() call:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  actionButton("test1", "test1"),
  actionButton("test2", "test2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$test1 | input$test2, { print('Hello World') } , ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have an action button within a modal. In order to prevent the modal  button initialization from triggering the observe event, I must generate 2 separate observe events. This method works.

```
employee <- shiny::reactiveVal(DBI::dbReadTable(pool, "employee") |> 
dplyr::mutate(actions = ""))

shiny::observeEvent(label = "Refresh employee table on add", eventExpr = 
input$submit, {
    employee(DBI::dbReadTable(pool, "employee"))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

shiny::observeEvent(label = "Refresh employee on delete", eventExpr = 
input$yes_button, {
    employee(DBI::dbReadTable(pool, "employee"))}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```