# How to sync 'selectizeInput' between menu items for 'navbarPage' in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, menu, navbar

Let see the following code of R Shiny dashboard with 'navbarPage' layout and 2 items "Page one" and "Page two" in the main menu. Each page has selector "Selector" with the same elements (1, 2, 3). There is an issue how to sync two 'selectizeInput' elements to show the same value.

For example, if selected "2" on "Page one" - the selector on "Page two" should have "2" value when user go to "Page two" and vice verse. I guess some kind of globall variable for the R session could be use. Will be glad to know your ideas and code how it can be implemented efficiently.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # 1. Selector for 'Page one'
  output$uo_page_one_selector <- renderUI({

    # 1. Values
    list_values <- c(1:3)
    names(list_values) <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

    # 2. Index of selected element
    index_selected <- 1

    # 3. Result
    selectizeInput('si_page_one_selector', "Selector",
               choices = list_values, multiple = FALSE, 
               selected = list_values[index_selected])
  })

  # 2. Selector for 'Page two'
  output$uo_page_two_selector <- renderUI({

    # 1. Values
    list_values <- c(1:3)
    names(list_values) <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

    # 2. Index of selected element
    index_selected <- 1

    # 3. Result
    selectizeInput('si_page_two_selector', "Selector",
               choices = list_values, 
               multiple = FALSE, 
               selected = list_values[index_selected])
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage("Demo",

    tabPanel("One",
         fluidPage(
           fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_page_one_selector")),
           fluidRow("Page one"))),

    tabPanel("Two",
         fluidPage(
           fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_page_two_selector")),
           fluidRow("Page two")))

  )
)

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 4):

We can create a global `reactiveVal` then update it whenever user click `si_page_one_selector` or `si_page_two_selector`

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
list_values <- c(1:3)
names(list_values) <- c("One", "Two", "Three")
rv = reactiveVal(1)
observeEvent(input$si_page_one_selector,{
tmp = rv() # Read reactiveVal
tmp = input$si_page_one_selector
rv(tmp) # set reactiveVal to new value
})

observeEvent(input$si_page_two_selector,{
tmp = rv()
tmp = input$si_page_two_selector
rv(tmp)
})
# 1. Selector for 'Page one'
output$uo_page_one_selector <- renderUI({
# 3. Result
selectizeInput('si_page_one_selector', "Selector",
               choices = list_values, multiple = FALSE, 
               selected = list_values[as.numeric(rv())])
})

# 2. Selector for 'Page two'
output$uo_page_two_selector <- renderUI({
# 3. Result
selectizeInput('si_page_two_selector', "Selector",
               choices = list_values, 
               multiple = FALSE, 
               selected = list_values[as.numeric(rv())])
})

}

ui <- fluidPage(
navbarPage("Demo",
         tabPanel("One",
                  fluidPage(
                    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_page_one_selector")),
                    fluidRow("Page one"))),

         tabPanel("Two",
                  fluidPage(
                    fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_page_two_selector")),
                    fluidRow("Page two")))
)
)

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

PS: This solution based on @Florian's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914706/eventreactive-with-multiple-eventexpr-and-output-depends-on-which-eventexpr-trig)

Comment: Thanks. It works in one way "Page 2" => "Page 1" but not works sometime "Page 1" => "Page 2". Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you do this from the server side with `updateSelectizeInput`?  I have 50000 genes and it's not possible to wait for the ui to load these and so I have been doing it from server side.

Comment: @BrianWiley I think it's possible, see **Examples** in `?shiny::updateSelectizeInput`, namely by using `oberserve`, otherwise post a new question, post the link here and I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: You know what, I am just trying to do too much with loading lot of genes, use placeholder in options (can only do this if items in options is set to empty list) as well as using score function to match beginning of word.  I will just have user input twice.

Comment: I am probably seeing things :) but [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-sync-selectizeinput-between-menu-items-for-navbarpage-in-r-shiny/38851) seems to be working for me.  The first answer that is, Hadley's is basically your example.