# How to identify which event triggered in observeEvent with multiple events

Tags: shiny, reactive

I am referring to the solution in this thread here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960953/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-observeevent). The question asks how to implement `observeEvent` with multiple events.

My question: using the first reponse (using `list`), is there a way to check which event in the input list is triggered, maybe by identifying the input name or its index in the list? The reason I am trying do this is that in my code, the the list of events corresponds to some other list of outputs that I want to modify. Both of these lists are rather long to be implemented with individual `observeEvent`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  actionButton("test1", "test1"),
  actionButton("test2", "test2"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  toListen <- reactive({
    list(input$test1,input$test2)
  })
  observeEvent(toListen(), {
    if(input$test1 is triggered){
      do something
    } else if (input$test2 is triggered) {
            do something else}     
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```