# R Shiny - how to simplify the following code?

Tags: r, shiny, format, simplify

I would like to know how I can simplify the following code?

```
  observeEvent(input$structure_explorer_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("structure_explorer_form")
  })
  observeEvent(input$property_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("property_form")
  })
  observeEvent(input$structure_activity_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("structure_activity_form")
  })  
  observeEvent(input$structure_target_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("structure_target_form")
  })    
  observeEvent(input$target_id_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("target_id_form")
  }) 
  observeEvent(input$target_activity_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("target_activity_form")
  })  
  observeEvent(input$drug_target_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("drug_target_form")
  })    
  observeEvent(input$drug_info_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("drug_info_form")
  })  
  observeEvent(input$assay_id_refresh, {
    shinyjs::reset("assay_id_form")
  })
```

I have tried to apply this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960953/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-observeevent) but I am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a module with no ui and then pass the names of the inputs as the arguments while performing a loop.

```
reset_server <- function(id, refresh_button, refresh_name) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      observeEvent(refresh_button(), {
        shinyjs::reset(refresh_name, asis = TRUE)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

An example code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  c("assay_id_refresh", "drug_info_refresh", "drug_target_refresh") |>
    purrr::map(\(x) actionButton(inputId = x, label = x)),
  c("assay_id_form", "drug_info_form", "drug_target_form") |>
    purrr::map(\(x) selectInput(
      inputId  = x,
      label    = x,
      choices  = 1:10,
      multiple = TRUE
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  purrr::walk2(
    .x = c("assay_id_refresh", "drug_info_refresh", "drug_target_refresh"),
    .y = c("assay_id_form", "drug_info_form", "drug_target_form"),
    .f = ~ reset_server(
      id             = .x,
      refresh_button = reactive(input[[.x]]),
      refresh_name   = .y
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```r
xxx <- c(
  "structure_explorer_",
  "property_",
  ......
)

for(x in xxx) {
  observeEvent(input[[paste0(x, "refresh")]], {
    shinyjs::reset(paste0(x, "form"))
  })
}
```