# How to listen for several event expressions in an observe event in order to redraw a plot and re-initialize a reactiveVal

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want my shiny app to display a time series and want to implement a way to a) change the time period via a slider and b) have an option to switch between a monthly, quarterly and yearly time aggregate and have the slider adjust accordingly.
Since my final product will have to display a fairly large amount of data, I set up my time slider with a refresh button in order to prevent the plot from already being rendered while the user is still selecting their dates in the slider.
My issue is that upon switching between monthly, quarterly and yearly aggregation, the plot rerenders and runs into errors due to the values from the time slider not being updated yet.
Thus, I want an observeEvent to listen to two seperate events: the refresh button of the time slider as well as the switch for the time aggregation. I already tried the solutions that were suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960953/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-observeevent) but I can't seem to get it to work.

My current code looks like this. My apologies if it appears to be lengthy, but I tried to build an example that included everything that to my understanding factors into the desired functionality:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

#random data
set.seed(123)
start_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2022-12-31")
months <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 month")
random_values <- runif(length(months), min = 0, max = 10)
data_frame <- data.frame(Time = months, Value = random_values)

#time slider function

create_time_slider <- function(aggregation){
  
  switch(aggregation,
         'mly' =       sliderTextInput(
           inputId = "timePeriod",
           label = tags$div(
             style = "width: 100px;",
             "Time period",
             actionButton(
               inputId = "Refresh_Time_Period",
               label = NULL,
               icon = icon("refresh"),
               class = "btn-xs",
               style = "float: right;"
             )
           ),
           choices = unique(as.character(data_frame$Time)),
           selected = c(as.character(min(data_frame$Time)), as.character(max(data_frame$Time)))
           ),
         'qly' =       sliderTextInput(
           inputId = "timePeriod",
           label = tags$div(
             style = "width: 100px;",
             "Time period",
             actionButton(
               inputId = "Refresh_Time_Period",
               label = NULL,
               icon = icon("refresh"),
               class = "btn-xs",
               style = "float: right;"
             )
           ),
           #label = tags$span(icon("calendar", "thin")),
           choices = unique(as.character(as.yearqtr(data_frame$Time))),
           selected = c(as.character(as.yearqtr(min(data_frame$Time))),as.character(as.yearqtr(max(data_frame$Time))))
         ),
         'yly' =       sliderTextInput(
           inputId = "timePeriod",
           label = tags$div(
             style = "width: 100px;",
             "Time period",
             actionButton(
               inputId = "Refresh_Time_Period",
               label = NULL,
               icon = icon("refresh"),
               class = "btn-xs",
               style = "float: right;"
             )
           ),
           #label = tags$span(icon("calendar", "thin")),
           choices = unique(year(data_frame$Time)),
           selected = c(as.character(min(year(data_frame$Time))),as.character(max(year(data_frame$Time))))
         )
  )
}

#plot function
myplot <- function(mindate, maxdate, aggr){
  switch(aggr,
         "mly" = data_frame <- data_frame %>% 
           mutate(Time = as.yearmon(Time)) %>% 
           filter(Time >= as.yearmon(mindate), Time <= as.yearmon(maxdate)),
         "qly" = data_frame <- data_frame %>% 
           mutate(Time = as.yearqtr(Time)) %>% 
           filter(Time >= as.yearqtr(mindate), Time <= as.yearqtr(maxdate)) %>% 
           group_by(Time) %>% summarise(Value = sum(Value)),
         "yly" = data_frame <- data_frame %>% 
           mutate(Time = year(as.Date(paste0(Time,"-01-01")))) %>% 
           filter(Time >= year(as.Date(paste0(mindate,"-01-01"))), Time <= year(as.Date(paste0(maxdate,"-01-01")))) %>% 
           group_by(Time) %>% summarise(Value = sum(Value))
  )
  highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = "Data Over 2 Years") %>%
    hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>%
    hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Value")) %>%
    hc_add_series(data = data_frame, type = "line", hcaes(x = Time, y = Value), name = "Value")
}


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      width = 12,
      column(
        width = 6,
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "aggregation",
          label = "time aggregation",
          choices = c("mly","qly","yly"),
          selected = c("mly","qly","yly")[1],
          inline = F
          # multiple = F
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 6,
        align = "left",
        uiOutput("slider")
      )
      
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Data Chart",
        width = 12,
        highchartOutput("lineChart")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    create_time_slider(input$aggregation)
  })
  
  slider_values <- reactiveVal(c(as.character(min(data_frame$Time)), as.character(max(data_frame$Time))))
  
  observeEvent(input$Refresh_Time_Period, {
    slider_values(input$timePeriod)
  })

  output$lineChart <- renderHighchart({
    myplot(slider_values()[1], slider_values()[2], input$aggregation)
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried some variations along the lines of

```
  toListen <- reactive({
list(input$Refresh_Time_Period, input$aggregation
})

  observeEvent(toListen(), {
    slider_values(input$timePeriod)
  })
```

but unforunately that didn't work for me.
Ultimately, I need for the aggregation input to re-initialize slider_values depending on the selection of the aggregation input.

I hope that my problem and desired/expected result have become clear.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why didn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960953/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-observeevent work? What you have is neither of the examples given as options there. You either need `observeEvent(input$Refresh_Time_Period | input$aggregation)` or to create a `reactive` containing your `list` and then pass the reactive to `observeEvent`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm sorry, I simply pasted the wrong code snipped. I edited my original post. The `reactive` containing the `list` which is then passed to the `observeEvent` is exactly what I tried. It won't work and I'm not sure why. The `observeEvent(input$Refresh_Time_Period | input$aggregation)` approach doesn't work since the inputs are neither logical nor numerical.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am overlooking something important, but from my understanding:

1. Your plot should **not** take any dependency on `input$aggregation` (only your slider `input$timePeriod` should)
2. Your `reactiveVal` (`slider_values()`) holds the range from `input$timePeriod` but only gets updated upon click on `input$Refresh_Time_Period`.
3. Your plot should re-render when the slider `slider_values()` change.

Thus all you need to do is to `isolate` the dependency on `input$aggregation` in your render function.

You can additionally opt to force a change of `slider_values()` whenever you change `input$aggregation`.

I would furthermore use `updateLiderTextInput` instead of totally re-rendering the slider for less replication:

```r
ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Data Dashboard"),
   dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
         column(
            6,
            radioButtons("aggregation", "time aggregation", c("mly","qly","yly"),
                         "mly", FALSE)
         ),
         column(
            6,
            align = "left",
            sliderTextInput(
               "timePeriod",
               tags$div(
                  style = "width: 100px;",
                  "Time period",
                  actionButton("Refresh_Time_Period", NULL, icon("refresh"), 
                               class = "btn-xs", style = "float: right;")
               ),
               choices = unique(as.character(data_frame$Time)),
               selected = as.character(range(data_frame$Time))
            )
         )
      ),
      fluidRow(
         box(
            title = "Data Chart",
            width = 12,
            highchartOutput("lineChart")
         )
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   slider_values <- reactiveVal(as.character(range(data_frame$Time)))
   
   observeEvent(input$aggregation, {
      ch <- switch(input$aggregation,
                   mly = unique(as.character(data_frame$Time)),
                   qly = unique(as.character(as.yearqtr(data_frame$Time))),
                   yly = unique(year(data_frame$Time)))
      sel <- range(ch)
      updateSliderTextInput(session, "timePeriod", choices = ch, selected = sel)
      ## remove if plot should **NOT** be updated upon aggregation level change
      slider_values(sel) 
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$Refresh_Time_Period, {
      slider_values(input$timePeriod)
   })
   
   output$lineChart <- renderHighchart({
      myplot(slider_values()[1], slider_values()[2], isolate(input$aggregation))
   })
   
   session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      stopApp()
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That did exactly what I needed it to do. For whatever reason I was convinced that I had to listen to both inputs (`Refresh_Time_Period` and `aggregation` simultaneously. Also thank you for suggesting to use `updateSliderTextInput`, that is certainly a better solution. Could you explain a little more why you isolated `aggregation` in the plot rendering? I see no difference running the code with or without the isolation and I would have thought that I certainly need the plot to be dependant on `aggregation` since it affects the data itself.

Comment: Well, if you take a dependency on `input$aggregation` it can happen that the `render` function fires *before*  the slider was updated and then you will see an error. In any case it is not necesary at all because it depends anyways indreictly on it via `aggregation -> slider_values -> render`