# eventReactive with 2 action button across 2 tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app with 2 tabs, each has an action button. I want the same process to be triggered if either buttons is pressed. So I wrote it the following way:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tab1",
      actionButton("btn1","Button 1"),
      textOutput("text")
    ),
    tabPanel("tab2",
      actionButton("btn2","Button 2")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data=eventReactive(c(input$btn1,input$btn2),{
    print("Button is pressed!")
    print(input$btn1)
    print(input$btn2)
    iris
  })
  output$text=renderText({
    req(data())
    print(head(data()))
    "Really? Button is pressed!"
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And I don't understand why the `eventReactive` expression is triggered when the app initialize, before any button is pressed.

If I only work with 1 button, i.e. `input$btn1` instead of `c(input$btn1, input$btn2)` then I get the expected behaviour, but not with 2 dependencies.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

`eventReactive` has a argument `ignoreInit`, which defaults to `False`, see `help(eventReactive)`.

Your issue is resolved my modifying the following line:

```
data=eventReactive(c(input$btn1,input$btn2),{
```

to

```
data=eventReactive(c(input$btn1,input$btn2),ignoreInit = T,{
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: your solution does indeed work. But I still don't understand the behaviour. 1. the doc says "Unlike what happens for `ignoreNULL`, only `observeEvent` takes in an `ignoreInit` argument." Well, clearly eventReactive takes that argument as well. 2. It seems to me this solution is suppressing the `valueExpr` rather than the trigger (`eventExpr`). 3. Why would one button work?

Comment: I think that is a mistake in the documentation, since the argument is available for both. I have created an issue for this on [Github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1907), let's see if we are correct ;)

Comment: Finally closed by https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/2036. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the expression automatically evaluates to TRUE and hence it executes on load. Rather you should be using `{}` [to listen from two buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha).

Modified code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tab1",
             actionButton("btn1","Button 1"),
             textOutput("text")
    ),
    tabPanel("tab2",
             actionButton("btn2","Button 2")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data=eventReactive({
    input$btn2
    input$btn1},{
    print("Button is pressed!")
    print(input$btn1)
    print(input$btn2)
    iris
  })
  output$text=renderText({
    req(data())
    print(head(data()))
    "Really? Button is pressed!"
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't think this solution works. I makes the trigger an 'AND' condition. That is, both buttons need to be pressed before something happen. Of course, I don't understand why this would be the case either.