# Store input from one action button permanently so as to use it later

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a dashboard (which I made using "shinydashboard" package).

**Purpose of dashboard**

The dashboard shows query results for different quarters in different tabs, with separate SQL queries in each tab. The schemas in the database have granted access to only certain users, so if a user is not authenticated, he wont be able to see the query results.

**Required action**

For the authentication process, the home page of the dashboard asks the user for the following

- username
- password
- latest quarter ( to be used in the SQL query as an input)
- penultimate latest quarter ( to be used in the SQL query as an input)

**Question (See sample code below for the ui and server)**

Once the user clicks the "home_act" action button, I want to store that value for use in all further tabs. Each tab will have a "tab_{no}_act" action button which, when clicked, should yield the corresponding tab's SQL query result using values from the stored input from the home tab. What I do not want is for the user to go back and click the "home_act" action button every time he has to execute each individual tab.

An ideal behaviour for the dashboard is:

- User opens dashboard, enters credentials on "Home" tab.
- Goes to "Tab 1",clicks submit and gets sql tab_1 query result
- Goes to "Tab 2",clicks submit and gets sql tab_2 query result.

  I have tried storing the values using reactiveValues() function and passing them on to different reactives, but it doesn't work. Please let me know what I have to change/ which new function I should use.

**Reproducible Sample code**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(RPostgres)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab_1"),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab_2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "home",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_latest_qtr",label = "Most Recent Quarter")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_pnltmt_latest_qtr",label = "Penultimate Latest Quarter")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_user",label = "Database Username")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         passwordInput(inputId = "home_pwd",label = "Database Password")),
                  column(12,
                         actionButton(inputId = "home_act",label = "Home Submit"))
                  )
                )
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_1",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         actionButton("tab_1_act","Tab 1 Submit"))
                )
                ,
                dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab_1_output")
                
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_2",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         actionButton("tab_2_act","Tab 2 Submit"))
                )
                ,
                dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab_2_output")
                
              )
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  user_credentials <- reactiveValues(user = '', pwd = '',latest_qtr = '',pnltmt_latest_qtr = '')
  observeEvent(input$home_act,{
    user_credentials$user <- input$home_user
    user_credentials$pwd <- input$home_pwd
    user_credentials$latest_qtr <- input$home_latst_qtr
    user_credentials$pnltmt_latest_qtr <- input$home_pnltmt_latest_qtr
  })
  
  tab_1_sql <- reactive({
    paste0("
           select * from table_1
           where quarter = '",user_credentials$latest_qtr,"' 
           limit 100
           ;")
  })
  
  tab_2_sql <- reactive({
    paste0("
           select * from table_1
           where quarter = '",user_credentials$pnltmt_latest_qtr,"' 
           limit 100
           ;")
  })
  
  tab_1_reactive <- reactive({
    if(user_credentials$user == '' | user_credentials$pwd == '')
    return()
    data.table::as.data.table(
      RPostgres::dbGetQuery(RPostgres::dbConnect(
        drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
        host = "xyz.com",
        port = 1234,
        dbname = 'db',
        user = user_credentials$user,
        password = user_credentials$pwd), tab_1_sql())
    )
    
  })
  
  tab_2_reactive <- reactive({
    if(user_credentials$user == '' | user_credentials$pwd == '')
      return()
    data.table::as.data.table(
      RPostgres::dbGetQuery(RPostgres::dbConnect(
        drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
        host = "xyz.com",
        port = 8888,
        dbname = 'db',
        user = user_credentials$user,
        password = user_credentials$pwd), tab_2_sql())
    )
    
  })
  
  output$tab_1_output <- renderDataTable({
    tab_1_reactive()
  })
  
  output$tab_2_output <- renderDataTable({
    tab_2_reactive()
  })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research from this post [How to listen for more than one event expression within a Shiny eventReactive handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha) , I got a working solution using observeEvent instead of reactiveValues.
Here is the code

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(RPostgres)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab_1"),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab_2")    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "home",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_latest_qtr",label = "Most Recent Quarter")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_pnltmt_latest_qtr",label = "Penultimate Latest Quarter")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         textInput(inputId = "home_user",label = "Database Username")),
                  column(3,offset = 0,
                         passwordInput(inputId = "home_pwd",label = "Database Password")),
                  column(12,
                         actionButton(inputId = "home_act",label = "Home Submit"))
                )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_1",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         actionButton("tab_1_act","Tab 1 Submit"))
                )
                ,
                dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab_1_output")

              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_2",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         actionButton("tab_2_act","Tab 2 Submit"))
                )
                ,
                dataTableOutput(outputId = "tab_2_output")

              )
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  tab_1_sql <- reactive({
    paste0("
           select * from table_1
           where quarter = '",input$home_latest_qtr,"' 
           limit 100
           ;")
  })

  tab_2_sql <- reactive({
    paste0("
           select * from table_1
           where quarter = '",input$home_pnltmt_latest_qtr,"' 
           limit 100
           ;")
  })

  observeEvent(
    {input$home_act
      input$tab_1_act},{
        tab_1_reactive <- reactive({
        data.table::as.data.table(
      RPostgres::dbGetQuery(RPostgres::dbConnect(
        drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
        host = "xyz.com",
        port = 1234,
        dbname = 'db',
        user = input$home_user,
        password = input$home_pwd), tab_1_sql())
    )

  })
  output$tab_1_output <- renderDataTable({
    tab_1_reactive()
  })
      })

  observeEvent({
    input$home_act
    input$tab_2_act},
    {
  tab_2_reactive <- reactive({
    data.table::as.data.table(
      RPostgres::dbGetQuery(RPostgres::dbConnect(
        drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
        host = "xyz.com",
        port = 1234,
        dbname = 'db',
        user = input$home_user,
        password = input$home_pwd), tab_2_sql())
    )

  })
  output$tab_2_output <- renderDataTable({
    tab_2_reactive()
  })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```