# Q: R Shiny Reactivity, 1 of 2 events

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have code that works when updating shiny, but I would like to change the event handling to occur when 1 of 2 events occurs rather than when both events occur.  Right now, the user must update both drop-down menus for graphs to update (input$company and input$peer).  I would like the plot to work if either of the events occur.  I suppose I could do this another way other than observeEvent, but I am new to this.  Thanks for the help.

Server.R

```
 server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent({
    input$company
    input$peer},{

  company_Bal <- data %>%
    select(Company, Date, End_Bal, Product) %>%
    filter(Product == "xxx", Company %in% input$company) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(End_Bal = sum(End_Bal, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    collect()

  Peer_Bal <- data %>%
    select(Company, Date, End_Bal, Product) %>%
    filter(Product == "xxx", Company %in% input$peer) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(End_Bal = sum(End_Bal, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    collect()


  output$hist <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(mode = 'lines')%>%
      add_lines(
        data =  company_Bal, 
        x = ~Date, 
        y = ~End_Bal,
        marker = list(
          size = 6, 
          color = 'rgba(31,119,180,0.0)',
          line = list(
            color = 'rgb(31,119,180)',
            width = 2
            )

          ),
        name = list(input$company), showlegend = TRUE) %>%
      add_lines(
        data =  Peer_Bal,
        x = ~Date,
        y = ~End_Bal,
        mode = 'lines',
        marker = list(
          size = 6, 
          color = 'rgba(31,119,180,0.0)',
          line = list(
            color = 'rgb(31,119,180)',
            width = 2
          )

        ),
        name = list(input$peer),showlegend = TRUE) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "", ticks= company_Bal$Date), showlegend = T, legend = list(orientation = "h", xanchor = "center",x = 0.5))

  })
  })
```

Comment: Specifically see this answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40351171/2372064. Try `observeEvent(c( input$company, input$peer), ...)` instead.

Comment: NM MrFlick, pointed out the quick solution, thanks.