# Shiny modal dialog in response to multiple buttons

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

Consider the following app:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  actionButton('button1', 'click one'),
  actionButton('button2', 'click two')
)
server <- function(input, output){
  popup <- function(){
    modalDialog(easyClose = T,
                'popup window triggered')
  }
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

My goal is that the modal window is triggered once either of the buttons is clicked. I realise that I can create an `observeEvent` for each button, but in the full application there will be many buttons on different `navbar` pages. So in order to avoid a whole bunch of code duplication, I would like to gather them in a single `observeEvent`. I tried some of the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha).

Adding

```
 observeEvent({
    input$button1
    input$button2
    }, {
    showModal(popup())
  })
```

to `server()` doesn't really work, because for some odd reason `button2` needs to be clicked before `button1` is responsive.

Instead, adding

```
  observeEvent(c(input$button1, input$button2), {
    showModal(popup())
  })
```

causes the modal window to appear on startup already, which should not happen.

So is there a way to capture multiple action buttons into a single observe event without these undesirable behaviours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `ignoreInit = TRUE` for `observeEvent`:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  actionButton('button1', 'click one'),
  actionButton('button2', 'click two')
)
server <- function(input, output){
  popup <- function(){
    modalDialog(easyClose = T,
                'popup window triggered')
  }

  observeEvent(c(input$button1, input$button2), {
    showModal(popup())
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```