# reactive invalidation based on (boolean) reactive conditional

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive `rv` and a reactive boolean `rv.haschanged` defined in the following way:

```
rv <- reactive({
  rv.haschanged()

  rv.haschanged(FALSE)

  cars[sample.int(nrow(cars), 1),] # return cars dataset as an example
})

rv.haschanged <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
```

Now there is some observer, for example, that can set `rv.haschanged` to `TRUE`.

```
observe({
    # do something...

    rv.haschanged(TRUE)
})
```

What I want is `rv` to update itself only when `rv.haschanged` is changed to `TRUE` (and not when `rv.haschanged` is changed to `FALSE`). The problem with the above code is that it will update `rv` twice. One time after observer executes `rv.haschanged(TRUE)`, and again due to `rv.haschanged(FALSE)`.

Any concise and intuitive idioms to achieve the above?

*Edit*: basically, all I want is to invalidate `rv` in the observer, so it schedules for re-execution.

Comment: When should `rv` update? If you don't want it to be invalidated by changes to `rv.haschanged` you can change it to an `eventReactive` so it only gets invalidated by changes to things in its `eventExpr`

Comment: @divibisan indeed. `rv` is the reactive, and it should update when `rv.haschanged` is `TRUE`. It should not update when `rv.haschanged` is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you want is to `isolate` all uses of `rv.haschanged` in your reactive expression so they don't invalidate the expression and then use an intermediate reactive value that can incorporate the logic you want.

Instead of using changes in `rv.haschanged()` to invalidate your reactive expression, we will make a new reactive Value called `check` which simply contains a counter that increments whenever `rv.haschanged` changes AND is `TRUE`

```
check <- reactiveVal(0)
observeEvent(rv.haschanged(), if (rv.haschanged() == TRUE) check(check() + 1))
```

Now, we can isolate `rv.haschanged()` in our reactive expression either using `isolate`:

```
rv <- reactive({
    check()
    isolate(rv.haschanged(FALSE))
    cars[sample.int(nrow(cars), 1),] # return cars dataset as an example
})
```

or by changing it to an `eventReactive`, which works like `reactive` but isolates everything inside the `valueExpr`:

```
rv <- eventReactive(check(), {
    rv.haschanged(FALSE)
    cars[sample.int(nrow(cars), 1),] # return cars dataset as an example
})
```

---

It's a bit of a hack, but to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to short-circuit the invalidation of a reactive expression: it's either valid (unchanged) or invalid (changed). What's served me well while working in shiny is breaking reactive expressions into smaller chunks (especially when they contain time-intensive tasks) to minimize the amount of code that has to re-run when something gets invalidated.

Comment: Thanks! +1, but `check()` feels a bit hackish to my taste. If no-one gives a better answer in a few days, I will accept yours.

Comment: It's less ugly if you use `reactiveValues` instead, so you don't need to have another separate `reactiveVal` floating around. You could also give it a more descriptive name, like `rv$rv.haschanged.check`.

Comment: But, yeah, it's kind of a hack. I'd truly love to see a better way if it's out there

Comment: I added an answer. Haven't tested it yet, but it wonder what you think of it.

Comment: @DavorJosipovic I think I misunderstood you and made your problem more complex than it actually was. Your code should keep `rv` from running twice, but it will get invalidated if anything else changes `rv.haschanged` to `FALSE`. My solution will only run `rv` if `rv.haschanged` changes to `TRUE`. That doesn't seem to be what you were looking for, is it?

Comment: Your answer is good. I am only looking for the most subtle solution. Subtle meaning "most comprehensible, concise, intuitive, etc.". There are a few ways I could solve this, but all my approaches seemed hackish, so I posted the question on SO. My own answer (if correct - will test tomorrow) is concise, but doesn't allow me to set `rv.haschanged` to `FALSE`. Only `TRUE` and `NULL`. I can live with that. Maybe I could also use `req()` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
rv <- eventReactive(rv.haschanged(), {      
  rv.haschanged(NULL)

  cars[sample.int(nrow(cars), 1),] # return cars dataset as an example
})

rv.haschanged <- reactiveVal(NULL)
```

And the observer:

```
observe({
    # do something...

    rv.haschanged(TRUE)
})
```

This exploits the `ignoreNULL = TRUE` option of `eventReactive`. So instead of using `FALSE`, we use `NULL`.

Note though that this [will not work if multiple objects are put in the `eventExpr` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182833/1548942).