# Using text input to calculate value for another text input in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, autofill, textinput

I would like to give the option to either input a percentage or a value. When the user inputs one of the two, I would like the other to autofill.

So for the code:

```
textInput(DownDollars, "Downpayment (Dollars)", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),

textInput(DownPercent, "Downpayment (Percent)", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)
```

Is there a way to use the output of these inputs to replace the `value =`  option?

UPDATE: Here is the code that doesn't work for using another input for the reference value:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("HomePrice", "Home Price", value = ""),
  
  numericInput("DownPaymentDollars", "Down Payment (Dollars)", value = "", width = NULL),
  
  numericInput("DownPaymentPercent", "Down Payment (Percent)", value = "", width = NULL)
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  #referenceValue <- 254
  
  observeEvent(input$DownDollars, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentPercent", value = input$DownDollars * 100 / input$HomePrice)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$DownPercent, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentDollars", value = input$DownPercent * input$HomePrice / 100)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Using updatetextInput could help: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateTextInput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's easier to use `numericInput` to get numeric values.
The following code does what you need:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("DownDollars", "Downpayment (Dollars)", value = "", width = NULL),
  
  numericInput("DownPercent", "Downpayment (Percent)", value = "", width = NULL)
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  referenceValue <- 254
  
  observeEvent(input$DownDollars, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPercent", value = input$DownDollars * 100 / referenceValue)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$DownPercent, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownDollars", value = input$DownPercent * referenceValue / 100)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I defined a referenceValue to calculate the percentage, you can define this value as you want, for example taken from another user input.

Be careful to define inputs IDs with quotes.

**EDIT**

When using another `numericInput` to get the reference value, you need to observe this new `numericInput` to update the calculations. One of the two `updateNumericInput` must be triggered by two `observeEvent` at the same time (see [this post explaining the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha)):

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("HomePrice", "Home Price", value = ""),
  numericInput("DownDollars", "Downpayment (Dollars)", value = "", width = NULL),
  
  numericInput("DownPercent", "Downpayment (Percent)", value = "", width = NULL)
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  
  observeEvent({
    input$HomePrice
    input$DownDollars
    }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPercent", value = input$DownDollars * 100 / input$HomePrice)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$DownPercent, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownDollars", value = input$DownPercent * input$HomePrice / 100)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! How would this change if the reference number was also from user input:

`numericInput("HomePrice", "Home Price", value = "")`

Simply changing to `value = input$DownDollars * 100 / input$HomePrice` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I updated the question to show my attempt to use another input for the reference value. No error message it just stops updating those other two inputs that you correctly got to work.

Comment: Ok this works once when starting the app but then you have to observe the reference value input to update the *Downpayment* inputs. See my updated answer for an attempt.

Comment: Thank you @julien.leroux5 ! This worked great! I've posted another question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/68957949/12886572) about this app if you are able to take a look.