# Using numeric inputs to generate datatable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, render, fluid

I am trying to make a shiny app where a user will input values that will then be used to generate a table. I have the code for the inputs:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("HomePrice", "Home Price", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50),
  numericInput("DownPaymentDollars", "Downpayment (Dollars)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50, width = NULL),
  numericInput("DownPaymentPercent", "Downpayment (Percent)", value = "", min = 0, max = 100, step = 0.05, width = NULL),
  numericInput("LoanAmount", "Loan Amount", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50, width = NULL),
  numericInput("InterestRate", "Interest Rate", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.0005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("TermYears", "Term (Years)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.5, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyPrincipleInterest", "Monthly Principle + Interest", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("PMIRate", "Annual PMI Rate", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.0005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyPMI", "Monthly PMI (Escrow)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyTaxes", "Monthly Taxes (Escrow)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyEscrow", "Monthly Escrow", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MinimumPayment", "Minimum Monthly Payment", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("ExtraMonthlyPayment", "Extra Monthly Payment", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL)
)
```

And I have some code for updating user inputs (like alternating between dollars and percents):

```
    server = function(input, output, session){
      
      observeEvent({
        input$HomePrice
        input$DownPaymentDollars
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentPercent", value = input$DownPaymentDollars * 100 / input$HomePrice)
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$HomePrice
        input$DownPaymentPercent
        }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentDollars", value = input$DownPaymentPercent * input$HomePrice / 100)
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$HomePrice
        input$DownPaymentDollars
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "LoanAmount", value = input$HomePrice - input$DownPaymentDollars)
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$LoanAmount
        input$InterestRate
        input$TermYears
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyPrincipleInterest", value = input$LoanAmount*((input$InterestRate/100/12)*((1+(input$InterestRate/100/12))^(input$TermYears*12)))/(((1+(input$InterestRate/100/12))^(input$TermYears*12))-1))
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$LoanAmount
        input$PMIRate
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyPMI", value = (input$PMIRate / 100) / 12 * input$LoanAmount)
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$LoanAmount
        input$MonthlyPMI
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "PMIRate", value = input$MonthlyPMI / input$LoanAmount * 12 * 100)
      })
    
      observeEvent({
        input$MonthlyPMI
        input$MonthlyTaxes
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyEscrow", value = input$MonthlyPMI + input$MonthlyTaxes)
      })
      
      observeEvent({
        input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest
        input$MonthlyEscrow
      }, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "MinimumPayment", value = input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest + input$MonthlyEscrow)
      })
}
```

I also have the code for making a dataframe using the inputs (though I haven't gotten this to work in the shiny app, when all of the `input$IDs` were just variables it works great:

```
  observeEvent({
    input$TermYears
    input$LoanAmount
    input$MonthlyPMI
    input$MonthlyTaxes
    input$InterestRate
    input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest
    input$ExtraMonthlyPayment
    input$HomePrice
  }, {
    Month <- seq(1, input$TermYears*12, 1)
    df <- data.frame(Month)
    df$PreviousBalance <- input$LoanAmount
    df$PMI <- input$MonthlyPMI
    df$Taxes <- input$MonthlyTaxes
    df$Interest <- df$PreviousBalance*(input$InterestRate/100/12)
    df$Principal <- input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest-df$Interest+input$ExtraMonthlyPayment
    df$EquityDollars <- input$HomePrice-df$PreviousBalance+df$Principal
    df$EquityPercent <- (df$EquityDollars/input$HomePrice)*100
    df$EndingBalance <- df$PreviousBalance-df$Principal
    x <- seq(1, input$TermYears*12, 1)
    for (i in x) {
      if(i > 1) {
        df$PreviousBalance[i] <- df$EndingBalance[i-1]
        if(df$EquityPercent[i-1]<20) {
          df$PMI[i] <- input$MonthlyPMI
        }
        else {
          df$PMI[i] <- 0
        }
        df$Taxes[i] <- input$MonthlyTaxes
        df$Interest[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]*(input$InterestRate/100/12)
        if(df$PreviousBalance[i]>df$Principal[i]) {
          df$Principal[i] <- input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest-df$Interest[i]+input$ExtraMonthlyPayment
        }
        else {
          df$Principal[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]
        }
        df$EquityDollars[i] <- input$HomePrice-df$PreviousBalance[i]+df$Principal[i]
        df$EquityPercent[i] <- (df$EquityDollars[i]/input$HomePrice)*100
        df$EndingBalance[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]-df$Principal[i]
      }
    }
    
    
  })
```

This is my first time doing this, how do I take this code for the table and put it into the shiny app so that once the user fills in all the numeric inputs (and clicks a submit button) it generates a table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To finish your work, you basically just need a so-called `actionButton` which will be your submit button, and have your last `observeEvent` wait for the submit button. I've completed your code below. I've also put a `print(df)` statement so that you can see the created table. To make sure all inputs have a value, you could also add as many call to `req(input$IDs)` as necessary. I included only one (`req(input$TermYears)`)  in the code below.

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("HomePrice", "Home Price", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50),
  numericInput("DownPaymentDollars", "Downpayment (Dollars)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50, width = NULL),
  numericInput("DownPaymentPercent", "Downpayment (Percent)", value = "", min = 0, max = 100, step = 0.05, width = NULL),
  numericInput("LoanAmount", "Loan Amount", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 50, width = NULL),
  numericInput("InterestRate", "Interest Rate", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.0005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("TermYears", "Term (Years)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.5, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyPrincipleInterest", "Monthly Principle + Interest", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("PMIRate", "Annual PMI Rate", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.0005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyPMI", "Monthly PMI (Escrow)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyTaxes", "Monthly Taxes (Escrow)", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MonthlyEscrow", "Monthly Escrow", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("MinimumPayment", "Minimum Monthly Payment", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  numericInput("ExtraMonthlyPayment", "Extra Monthly Payment", value = "", min = 0, max = NA, step = 0.005, width = NULL),
  actionButton("button", "Submit") # <=== here is the action button
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent({
    input$HomePrice
    input$DownPaymentDollars
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentPercent", value = input$DownPaymentDollars * 100 / input$HomePrice)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$HomePrice
    input$DownPaymentPercent
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "DownPaymentDollars", value = input$DownPaymentPercent * input$HomePrice / 100)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$HomePrice
    input$DownPaymentDollars
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "LoanAmount", value = input$HomePrice - input$DownPaymentDollars)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$LoanAmount
    input$InterestRate
    input$TermYears
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyPrincipleInterest", value = input$LoanAmount*((input$InterestRate/100/12)*((1+(input$InterestRate/100/12))^(input$TermYears*12)))/(((1+(input$InterestRate/100/12))^(input$TermYears*12))-1))
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$LoanAmount
    input$PMIRate
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyPMI", value = (input$PMIRate / 100) / 12 * input$LoanAmount)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$LoanAmount
    input$MonthlyPMI
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "PMIRate", value = input$MonthlyPMI / input$LoanAmount * 12 * 100)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$MonthlyPMI
    input$MonthlyTaxes
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "MonthlyEscrow", value = input$MonthlyPMI + input$MonthlyTaxes)
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest
    input$MonthlyEscrow
  }, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "MinimumPayment", value = input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest + input$MonthlyEscrow)
  })
  
  # here you wait for the action button to be triggered
  observeEvent({input$button}, {
    req(input$TermYears)
    Month <- seq(1, input$TermYears*12, 1)
    df <- data.frame(Month)
    df$PreviousBalance <- input$LoanAmount
    df$PMI <- input$MonthlyPMI
    df$Taxes <- input$MonthlyTaxes
    df$Interest <- df$PreviousBalance*(input$InterestRate/100/12)
    df$Principal <- input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest-df$Interest+input$ExtraMonthlyPayment
    df$EquityDollars <- input$HomePrice-df$PreviousBalance+df$Principal
    df$EquityPercent <- (df$EquityDollars/input$HomePrice)*100
    df$EndingBalance <- df$PreviousBalance-df$Principal
    x <- seq(1, input$TermYears*12, 1)
    for (i in x) {
      if(i > 1) {
        df$PreviousBalance[i] <- df$EndingBalance[i-1]
        if(df$EquityPercent[i-1]<20) {
          df$PMI[i] <- input$MonthlyPMI
        }
        else {
          df$PMI[i] <- 0
        }
        df$Taxes[i] <- input$MonthlyTaxes
        df$Interest[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]*(input$InterestRate/100/12)
        if(df$PreviousBalance[i]>df$Principal[i]) {
          df$Principal[i] <- input$MonthlyPrincipleInterest-df$Interest[i]+input$ExtraMonthlyPayment
        }
        else {
          df$Principal[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]
        }
        df$EquityDollars[i] <- input$HomePrice-df$PreviousBalance[i]+df$Principal[i]
        df$EquityPercent[i] <- (df$EquityDollars[i]/input$HomePrice)*100
        df$EndingBalance[i] <- df$PreviousBalance[i]-df$Principal[i]
      }
    }
    print(df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```